# How to make bot change all of the members nicknames?

Tags: discord.js

I have a question can't seem to find a way to do it, *I am new. My question is how can the bot change all of the members nick names? I searched ton of stack overflow sites but they didn't gave me the answer.

I have searched a ton of pages that I don't even remember.

---

Here is the picture [=picture=](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftHya.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will get all members and change there nicknames

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach((member) => member.setNickname("yo").catch(() => false))
```

I forgot **guild** ^^"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate it. However I am getting an error while doing it, it gives me this error of Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cache'). What should I do? I have heard to use fetch but I dont know how.

Comment: My fault, I forgot **guild** after **message**

Comment: Thx a lot now it works but only on bot.  I will update the picture

Comment: Also after checking when I change the nick of the bot like 9 times, it doesnt change anymore even when I restart the program. It doesn't update the nick

Comment: check that the bot's role is the highest, if that doesn't work try adding an `await guild.`